# Kinesis Firehose Not Sending Data to S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have set up a Kinesis stream with a Firehose that is supposed to take data that is put into the stream, and store it in an S3 bucket.

Currently I can see my stream is getting data and my firehose is reading it, but then not sending anything to S3.

Kinesis firehose reading data:

[image: Kinesis firehose reading data]

I can then see here that it is not delivering it to S3:

[image: Firehose not sending to S3]

The IAM role for the firehouse has access to read from Kinesis and read/write to S3.

[image: (screenshot of permissions)]

I set up logs but am not receiving any errors from the hose it seems.

Below is the serverless file i used to deploy everything.

Here is a link to serverless file for the firehose:

[image: Here is a link to serverless file for the firehose]

Here is a link to the other resources + policies for the role:

[image: Here is a link to the other resources + policies for the role]

Comment: Your kinesis stream policy seems to be lacking. Have a look at what it should be [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/controlling-access.html#using-iam-s3). Also please just paste code here, not the screenshots of code.

Comment: I don't have encryption on the stream so other than that part it looks like I have the same policies that they do (Describe stream, get records, get shard iterator, and list streams)..Is there something else i'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You may not be grating the right permissions.
Refer to this doc [Grant Kinesis Data Firehose Access to an Amazon S3 Destination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/controlling-access.html#using-iam-s3) to know the correct S3 and Kinesis `Actions` needed in the policy.

Or simply, go to your Kinesis Data Firehose page, open the IAM role link under Permissions, and **attach** the following policies to the role: `AmazonS3FullAccess`, `AmazonKinesisFullAccess` and `AmazonKinesisAnalyticsFullAccess`